# input type file onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to make the input type file dialog box pop up when the `onmouseover` event is triggred? Or any other event besides `onclick`? (I would like the dialog box to appear `onshake`, and I'm using a jQuery plugin for the shake event for mobile devices)

There's a hack where you can `onclick` on an item, and it would then click on the input type file element (which would be invisible) using JavaScript/jQuery, but it didn't work when I changed the item to `onmouseover` or another event.

**Edit:** My code looks a bit like this, except that I'm using the onshake event (with a jQuery plugin) instead of onmouseover. Some problem though:

```
<button onmouseover="javascript:opendialogbox('imageuploadform1');">nope!</button>
<script>
function opendialogbox(inputid){
document.getElementById(inputid).click();
}
</script>
<input type="file" id="imageuploadform1" name="picture" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can't:**

in this demo works on click : http://jsbin.com/eqenoz/1/edit

now try here with any other event : http://jsbin.com/eqenoz/2/edit

The action that opens a popup **MUST** be performed by the user itself and has to be a **DIRECT-USER-CLICK** event.
 So  mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave, shakeme, pushme, smileme, ... will not work and will throw a browser security warining.

The only thing you can do is ask your user to kindly confirm the warning exception.